# Nested aggregate functions with grouping in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, aggregate

I'm trying to get an average of sums using nested aggregate functions and grouping. What I would want to do is:

```
SELECT AVG(SUM(x) GROUP BY y) WHERE ... GROUP BY ...;
```

That is, for each row returned, I want one of the fields to be an average of sums, where each sum is over the rows where y is the same.

I would like to avoid subselects if possible.

Comment: "*I would like to avoid subselects if possible*". Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
select z, avg(sumval)
from (select y, z, sum(x) as sumval
      from t
      group by y, z
     ) t
group by z
```

Comment: But then for each row returned, I get a different z value, and the same average value. This is not the behaviour I want; for each z value, I want to get a corresponding average of sums particular to that value of z. For instance, if my data is

    `x  y z
    10 a g
    15 a g
    7  b g
    8  a h
    12 b h
    18 b h`

I would expect to have returned

    `z, average
    g  16
    h  19`

Comment: My original SQL was syntactically incorrect.  It should have had "z" as a grouping variable on the inner subquery.  I just fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for that:

```sql
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT y, z, sum(x) as sumval
    FROM t
    GROUP BY y, z
)
SELECT z, avg(sumval)
FROM tmp
GROUP BY z
```

Answer (score 0):

use over() clause:

```
SELECT y, AVG(SUM(x)) OVER(partition by y) WHERE ... GROUP BY ...;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16