# How to get the weighted average in sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to calculate the weighted average and have used the below query.

> ```
> select di.name, count(di.name)
> ,dmic.c_name, 
> sum(count(di.name)*dmic.c_price)/count(di.name) as avgPrice
> from di
> join..
> on..
> join..
> on..
> where...
> group by 1,3
> order by 2 desc;
> ```

And I am getting the error: aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function.
How can I work around this? I am looking to get the name, its occurrences and its weighted price in the output.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different database systems

Comment: According to Amazon ["Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) as it was forked from PostgreSQL 8. In fact, you still need to use pgsql 8 to connect. In your case most databases would fail though. You need a subquery or a CTE to calculate the aggregates before you combine them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested aggregate functions with grouping in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107666/nested-aggregate-functions-with-grouping-in-postgresql)

Comment: So far I have found that Redshift is based on postgres so I added both tags. However, removing the tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not really. The complexity seems to be arising as I am looking for the weighted average as well as the count of the items.

Comment: @rider7782 not really what? You can't nest aggregates. That's what the error tells you. The solution is to produce the intermediate aggregates and combine them. That's done either with a subquery or a CTE. Have you tried either solution?

Comment: I have already tried subqueries but I need to group by count(di.name) since its an extracted field and does not give me the sum of the count as what I am expecting

Comment: You can use VIEWS to emulate CTEs. [unfortunately, Pg-8 did not have TEMP VIEWS yet]

Comment: @rider7782: Redshift was never "forked" from Postgres. Amazon only took the code of the Postgres SQL _parser_ - everything else is completely different. In my opinion Amazon's claim that Redshift is "based" on Postgres is a marketing lie.